# Word 2010 Styles and Templates

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm currently writing my thesis and found a template which worked great at the start. Using the styles I am able to use Heading 1, Heading 2 and so on and as I start a new chapter the numbers increment. Heading 2 for example inserts 1.1, if I insert Heading 2 again it inserts 1.2 and so on. The only problem I'm having is with Heading 1. I want it to insert Chapter 1, Chapter 2 etc etc but at the moment it just inserts a black rectangle [image]

If I enter text I get the following [image].

I've looked at the style for H1 but I cant see what I need to change

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please add the contents of the style description to your question.  I mean the box in the Modify Style window starting with "Font 22pt, Bold, Kern at 14pt"

Comment: Font: 22 pt, Bold, Kern at 14 pt
    Line spacing:  Double, Space
    After:  12 pt, Keep with next, Level 1
    Tab stops:  0.63 cm, List tab, Outline numbered + Level: 1 + Numbering Style: One, Two, Three … + Start at: 1 + Alignment: Left + Aligned at:  0 cm + Indent at:  0 cm, Style: Quick Style
    Based on: Normal
    Following style: Normal    I've started from scratch with a different template / style and its working. God knows what was wrong with the previous template? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

First thought:

In the Modify Style window, press **Format**, **Borders**.
Open the **Shading** tab.
Change **Fill** to **No Color**.

Comment: Didn't work but thanks for the suggestion :-). If I select View->Outline and untick "Show Text Formatting" it displays the heading correctly??? I've started from scratch with a new template which has involved copying and pasting 50k words by section but the problem is now sorted.

Comment: I'm glad you got it going in the end.  Sometimes cut-and-paste is the fastest solution.